# Stopping Fitnesse (Slim) on any exception

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

We've found the "[Fail Fast](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf)" principle crucial for improving maintainability of our large Fitnesse-based battery of tests. Slim's [StopTestException](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ExceptionHandling) is our saviour.

However, it's very cumbersome and counterproductive to catch and convert any possible exception to those custom StopExceptions. And this approach doesn't work outside of fixtures. Is there a way to tell fitnesse (preferably using Slim test system) to stop test on any error / exception?

**Update**: corresponding feature request https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/issues/935

Answer (score 0):

Most of the exceptions coming from fixtures are possible to conveniently convert to the `StopTestException` by implementing the `FixtureInteraction` interface, e.g.:

```
public class StopOnException extends DefaultInteraction {

    @Override
    public Object newInstance(Constructor<?> constructor, Object... initargs) throws InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        try {
            return super.newInstance(constructor, initargs);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new StopTestException("Instantiation failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object methodInvoke(Method method, Object instance, Object... convertedArgs) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        try {
            return super.methodInvoke(method, instance, convertedArgs);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new StopTestException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static class StopTestException extends RuntimeException {

        public StopTestException(String s, Throwable e) {
            super(s, e);
        }
    }
}
```